# Finding ID of row when grouping by colunm A and ordering by column B

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that consists of many columns, but only three are relevant:

```
id - INT
species - VARCHAR(5)
date - DATE
```

I want to find the following: 
For each species, give me the id with the lowest date

Example data for one species:

```
id  | species | date
----------------------------
123 | 03100   | 2007-04-23
----------------------------
324 | 03100   | 2005-05-26
```

I've tried doing a GROUP BY ORDER

```sql
SELECT * FROM `table` GROUP BY species ORDER BY `date` ASC;

RESULT:
id  | species | date
----------------------------
123 | 03100   | 2007-04-23
```

I've tried ordering in a sub select before grouping:

```sql
SELECT 
    id, species, `date`
FROM
    (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        `table`
    ORDER BY `date` ASC) sub
GROUP BY species;

RESULT:
id  | species | date
----------------------------
123 | 03100   | 2007-04-23
```

The result should be

```
id  | species | date
----------------------------
324 | 03100   | 2005-05-26
```

because the date is the earliest for that species.

We have around 1100 distinct species, so I would prefer if it could be done in a single query instead of doing 1100 queries, one for each species.

UPDATE: 
I apologize in advance, your suggestion are good but I am having a hard time implementing them as my datamodel is a bit more complicated than the demo I posted:

```
TABLE: obs
------------------
id      | INT
species | VARCHAR
user_id | INT
trip_id | INT

TABLE: trips
------------------
trip_id | INT
dato    | DATE
```

In reality, I have to join `obs` and `trips` together to get the date, and then I have to find the id, species and date for a specific `user_id`

I hope you can still help me :-)

Regards, 
Anders

Answer (score 0):

If you want the earliest record, I would recommend *filtering*, not aggregation.  I would use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select min(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.species = t.species);
```

If you can have multiple dates and you want only one record per id, then you can adjust this to:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select t2.id
              from t t2
              where t2.species = t.species
              order by t2.date asc, t2.id asc
             );
```